# In flutter I am getting user input in form which I wants to save.But i am facing issue where 1 integer field can be null and user may/may not fill it

Tags: flutter, api, dart, integer, dart-null-safety

On the click of below elevated button I am calling method and sending all data collected from user.Its working fine with string values means whenever user fills or not fills the data for those string values it still saves the data but when user don't fill int field it doesn't saves it. The form should be saved even if user don't fill the int field:

```
 Container(

              //alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 35,
              width: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 89, 168),
              ),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                // style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                //   backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                //   shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                //   // shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: borderRadius),
                // ),
                onPressed: () {
                  //  _formKey.currentState?.validate();
                  // final isValidForm = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
                  //  if (isValidForm) {
                  final aptId = apID;
                  print('apt id add $aptId');

                  final int docId = dID;

                  print('doc id add $dID');
                  final int staffId = staff_Id;
                  print('add staff id $staffId');

                  final String partyName = partyNameController.text;
                  final String partyType = selectedValue.toString();
                  final String aptStatus = selectedItem.toString();
                  final String? paymentMode = selectedMode.toString();
                  //final String paymentMode = paymentModeController.text;
                  final String aptplace = aptplaceController.text;

                  final String city = cityController.text;

                  final String aptDate = aptDateController.text;

                  final String aptTime = aptTimeController.text;

                  final int? feesCollected =
                      int.parse(feesCollectedController.text).toInt();

                  final int totalFees =
                      int.parse(totalFeesController.text).toInt();

                  final String contactNo = contactNoController.text;

                  final String? comments = commentsController.text;

                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => AppointmentPageFE()));

                  setState(() {
                    _futureAppointment = createAppointment(
                      aptId,
                      docId,
                      staffId,

                      partyName,
                      contactNo,
                      partyType,
                      aptplace,
                      city,
                      feesCollected ?? 0,
                      totalFees,
                      paymentMode ?? '',
                      aptDate,
                      aptTime,
                      // aptExecutive,
                      aptStatus,
                      comments ?? '',
                    );
                  });
                  // }
                  // }
                },
                child: const Text("Save"),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 89, 168))),
              ))
```

The mothod where API is calling:

```
Future<Appointment> createAppointment(
      int? aptId,
      int docId,
      int staffId,
      //String docTitle,
      // String tokenNo,
      String partyName,
      String contactNo,
      String partyType,
      String aptPlace,
      String city,
      int? feesCollected,
      int totalFees,
      String paymentMode,
      String aptDate,
      String aptTime,
      // String aptExecutive,
      String aptStatus,
      String comments,
      // String createdAt,
    ) async {
      final response = await http.put(
          // Uri.parse('http://192.168.0.134:8080/AtdochubJ-3/appointment/register'),
          Uri.parse('http://3.108.194.111:8080/AtdochubJ-3/appointment/register'
    
              // 'http://3.108.194.111:8080/AtdochubJ-3/appointment/register'
              ),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          },
          body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
            'aptId': aptId,
            'docId': docId,
            'staffId': staffId,
            // 'docTitle': docTitle,
            // 'tokenNo': tokenNo,
            'partyName': partyName,
            'contactNo': contactNo,
            'partyType': partyType,
            'aptPlace': aptPlace,
            'city': city,
            'feesCollected': feesCollected ?? 0,
            'totalFees': totalFees,
            'paymentMode': paymentMode,
            'aptDate': aptDate,
            'aptTime': aptTime,
            //'aptExecutive': aptExecutive,
            'aptStatus': aptStatus,
    
            'comments': comments,
            //  'createdAt': createdAt,
          }));
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Appointment Scheduled Successfully",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 77, 171, 248),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 12.0);
        print("response.statusCode ${'successful'}");
        return Appointment.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
      } else {
        if (response.statusCode == 500) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Internal Server Error !",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
              gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 77, 171, 248),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 12.0);
        } else {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Failed to schedule appointment",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
              gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 77, 171, 248),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 12.0);
        }
      }
      throw Exception(' Failed To Create Appointment');
    }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: FormatException @eamirho3ein

Comment: could you include the error and the place it happened?

Comment: whenever I press the button nothing happens it remains on same screen and just throws format exception

Comment: Whenever i press the button nothing happens. it remains on the same screen and throws format exception to the console @eamirho3ein

Comment: we need to see the error message to get where is the problem

Comment: js_primitives.dart:30 Another exception was thrown: FormatException @eamirho3ein